# I want to make a1=0, a2=0.. aN=0

Tags: python

I want to make a1=0, a2=0,...  aN=0.
I thought using "for"

For example N=10

```
for i in range(0, 10):

   print('a%d'%i)
```

but it isn't not zeros(just print).
So, I did 'a%d'%i=0. but It didn't work

How can I make that?

Comment: Do you want to print them or use them for calculation purposes?

Comment: I'm just curious stuyding python. :) thx everybody replied my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For printing use [`.format()` (or f-strings on python 3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) :

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print('a{} = {}'.format(i,i))  # the 1st i is put into the 1. {}, the 2nd i is put ...
```

If you want to calculate with those as names, store them into a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and use the values to calculate with them:

```
d = {}
for i in range(0, 10):
    d["a{}".format(i)] = i # the nth i is put instead nth {}

print("sum a4 to a7:  {} + {} + {} + {} = {}".format(   # use the values stored in dict to 
    d["a4"], ["a5"], ["a6"], ["a7"],                    # calculate and print the single 
    d["a4"]+d["a5"]+d["a6"]+d["a7"]))                   # values where needed
```

Output:

```
# for loop 
a0 = 0
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
a3 = 3
a4 = 4
a5 = 5
a6 = 6
a7 = 7
a8 = 8
a9 = 9

# calculation
sum a4 to a7:  4 + ['a5'] + ['a6'] + ['a7'] = 22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary for that.

```
var_name = 'a'

for i in range(0, 10):   
    key = var_name + str(i) # an
    new_values[key] = 0 # assign 0 to the new name
```

For accessing them individually,

```
new_values['a1']
>>> 0
```

or you can access them all together like this,

```
for k,v in new_values.items():
    print(k,'=',v)
```

outputs:

```
a0 = 0
a1 = 0
a2 = 0
a3 = 0
a4 = 0
a5 = 0
a6 = 0
a7 = 0
a8 = 0
a9 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, using const value `x=0`, and counter `i`:

```
x = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    print(f"a{i} = {x}")
```

output:

```
a0 = 0
a1 = 0
a2 = 0
a3 = 0
a4 = 0
a5 = 0
a6 = 0
a7 = 0
a8 = 0
a9 = 0
```